# Access files priority in I/O operation with FORTRAN

Tags: linux, fortran

Can someone explain me how does the access to file for I/O operation works in Linux? I am using some Fortran script process big data. I have many files (say 100) and the Fortran script has to read a single file, do some operations, and then write some results in a new file. If I try to run different times the script on different groups of files (for example one run on 10 files) at the same time I don't get a reduction of the computational time. Does it mean that the system can't read and write to multiple files together?

Comment: This depends on a lot of things.  How many disks do you have and how many disk controllers drive them?  What kind of disks are they?  What protocol do they connect to the controller with (e.g. SATA, SAS, IDE, etc).  What is the read/write performance of the disks?  How much cache does the disk have? How many CPU cores do you have? Is your task IO bound or CPU bound (sounds like IO).